# How does the hex number 0x000000000032000000 correspond to 50 in decimal?

Tags: hex, decimal

I understand that 32 in hex is 50 in decimal, but with all the zeroes how do I get 50 from 0x000000000032000000 in hex?

Comment: 1. You don't. 2. How is this a programming question?

Comment: 0x000000000032 is 50.  But 0x000000000032000000 is not 50. Leading zeros are ignored but not trailing zeros .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get 50 by shifting this hexadecimal number 24 bit to right.